# Finding Difference In Months for 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how do i find the difference in months two dataframes which are in datetime64.

I tried this:

```
(df_A - df_B) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

but i get weird results like: -1 days +23:59:59.999999

Both dataframes are of the same dimensions and have the same indexes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
(df_A - df_B).astype('timedelta64[M]')
```

Just change 'M' if you are looking for differences in other datetime